# Is there a faster way to get the linkable portals list?

Tags: ingress

When you'are in a rush for linking (for example your bus stops or slows nearby a portal to only give you a few seconds to link from it) the worst thing is the build up speed of the linkable portals list. Some players claim that they experience this waiting time less than others. Are there really some tactics to speed up this portal scanning progress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a tactic to speed up the linkable portal list build time. If you put the possible linkable keys from that portal into a capsule excluding your target portals, the overall scanning time decreases giving you more time to complete the linking action. So if you have little time to link from a portal you should prepare yourself by putting possible unwanted target keys into a capsule before arriving to your target portal.

This tip has been approved by field trials by many players.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in a rush for linking, and the target portal is near enough to be visible on the scanner "linking view", you can select it and press link button even if it's not yet on the linkable list.